# How to configure proxy with Angular 17 (esbuild/vite)

Tags: proxy, angular17

I used to use a proxy with Angular <= 16, using webpack.

Switching to Angular 17 and default esbuild/vite, the proxy configuration does not seem to work anymore.

This configuration used to work:

```json
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following two ways to provide the config:

- `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
- Setting `proxyConfig` in angular.json

In both ways the configuration seems to be ignored.

I'm using Angular (including CLI) 17.0.8 and Node v18.17.0.

Thanks for your help!

I tried to provide the proxy configuration to Angular, expected it to proxy the requests, but the request were not proxied.

Comment: I am facing the same issue since I started using Angular 17 while in old versions it was working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two ** instead one *

this way:

```
{
    "/api/**": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
           "^/api": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! :D  But do you know why this is needed?